# How to visualize a Vue application's component hierarchy?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How to visualize a Vue js  application's component hierarchy ?. I know that thier is a React Sight that used for a live view of the component hierarchy tree of  React application.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are looking for something like the devtools? Check this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

Answer (score 1):

There's also [DejaVue](https://github.com/MiCottOn/DejaVue) however it hasn't been touched in 5 years. Works on Vue 2, may not work on Vue 3.